# How to improve build times with Firebase in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I'm using Firebase from Swift Package Manager in an iOS Objective-C app in Xcode.

Everything works fine, but there is a noticeable difference now launching my app from Xcode to simulator or device. I would say Firebase adds at least an extra 1-2 seconds in build time every time I launch my app.

Is there anyway to improve these build times with Firebase in Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're optimizing for build time, I suggest that you integrate Firebase as a binary framework rather than an SPM dependency.

I used to have similar build time issues with Firebase on relatively small apps. While incremental build times were tolerable, cold builds on CI were painfully long and that was the turning point for me. After integrating Firebase as a binary .xcframework my cold build times on CI dropped from 30-45 minutes down to 5 minutes.

1. Go to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks).
2. In the section that explains how to integrate it without a dependency manager you'll find a link to a .zip archive containing all Firebase frameworks.
3. Download the archive. The documentation claims that it's about 200 Mb in size however the one I recently download was almost 370 Mb.
4. Follow the instructions in Readme.md that you'll find inside the archive.

It's a bit painful to set it up for the first time and is a bit annoying to update Firebase manually from time to time, but for me the drop in build times was totally worth it.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Builds super fast now. I just can't seem to get Firestore to work. Authentication works fine and everything builds, but when I try to get the current Firestore instance `[FIRFirestore firestore]` it returns nil.